# Drop all tables with <String> in their name

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am looking for a function or sub (in a module) wich I can call to drop all tables that have "tbl" in their name. I have found several pieces of code that just don't work right.

---

To clarify my question:

I am working in Access. In my project, I use VBA to generate a few tables. I don't know what the names of these tables will be beforehand. I do know that the tables that I would like to delete ("DROP") have "tbl" in their name.

What I am looking for is code that does something like this:

```
DoCmd.runSQL (DROP ALL TABLE LIKE '%tbl%')
```

I know this code does not work, but it should give a little insight in what I would like to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have "access to Access" right now, but you may create a macro, something like:

```
Sub Delete_tbl
    Dim t as TableDef
    For Each t In CurrentDB.TableDefs
        If t.Name Like "tbl*" Then DoCmd.runSQL("DROP TABLE " & t.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I can not believe i have searched for this for over 4hours! works like a charm

Comment: obviously you can prefix with a further * "*tbl*" if you are unsure where in the string this will occur.

Comment: good solution. Anyone going to drop all tables, use `Not Like "MSys*"` to prevent (errors for) dropping Access' system tables